# Not getting any data from fileinput stream

Tags: java, excel, selenium, apache-poi

Currently exploring apache poi and what seems to be the error?
I didn't get any value from my filesheets.

Tried to prompt out the value from line 51 and I didn't get any.

This is what I'm doing: I identify test cases column by scanning the entire 1st row and once column is identified then scan entire testcase column to identify purchase testcase row after you grabbing purchase testcase row = I want to pull all the data of that row and feed into test

For the excel file

TIA

[image]

Code:

```
public class App {

    public ArrayList<String> getData(String testcaseName) throws IOException
    {

        ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();

        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("/Users/jaxethhugomahiya/Downloads/testData.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        int sheets=workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for(int i=0;i<sheets;i++)
        {
            if(workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("testdata"))
            {
                XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(i);


                Iterator<Row>  rows= sheet.iterator();// sheet is collection of rows
                Row firstrow= rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> ce=firstrow.cellIterator();//row is collection of cells
                int k=0;
                int column = 0;
                while(ce.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell value=ce.next();

                    if(value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Testcases"))
                    {
                        column=k;
                    }

                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println(column);


                while(rows.hasNext())
                {
                    Row r=rows.next();
if(r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testcaseName))
                    {
                        Iterator<Cell>  cv=r.cellIterator();
                        while(cv.hasNext())
                        {
                            Cell c= cv.next();
                            if(c.getCellType()==CellType.STRING)
                            {

                                a.add(c.getStringCellValue());
                            }
                            else{
 a.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(c.getNumericCellValue()));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;

    }
```

testSample.java

```
public static void main(String args) throws IOException{
    App a = new App();
    ArrayList<String> data = a.getData("Add Profile");
    System.out.println(data.get(0));
    System.out.println(data.get(1));
    System.out.println(data.get(2));
    System.out.println(data.get(3));
}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Try printing out any non-matching sheets and see if you're mistaken about what the sheet you want is actually called?

Comment: @Gagravarr it prompts 0 value which is corrects however from the arraylist it is throwing a Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 in data.get(0)

Comment: start adding `System.out.println("sheets: " + sheets);`; and inside the first loop `System.out.println("sheet " +  i + " = \"" + workbook.getSheetName(i) + "\"");`  - better: use a debugger to check these values and what is being executed

Comment: Apologies for the late update. Deleted the testSample.java and place the arraylist on  the main.

Answer (score 1):

Same under app, successfully read the excel file.
Thank you

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        App a = new App();
        ArrayList data = a.getData("Delete Profile");
        System.out.print(" "+data.get(0));
        System.out.print(" "+data.get(1));
        System.out.print(" "+data.get(2));
        System.out.print(" "+data.get(3));
    }
```